# Another way to iterate to get multiple values against single date column in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe df:
Multiple values for a single date.

```
         Date Title Description
0  2003-02-10     A         age
1  2003-02-10     B      number
2  2003-02-10     C       total
3  2003-02-10     D  percentage
4  2003-02-11     E    division
5  2003-02-12     F  cumulative
6  2003-02-13     G   ampersand
7  2003-02-13     H       value

news = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    date = row['Date']
    if date in news:
        news[date] += '\n' + df['Title'] + '\n' + df['Description']
    else:
        news[date] = '\n' + df['Title'] + '\n' + df['Description']
```

Problem : It takes way too long, and ends up with storage error, Is there any other way I can do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and string concatenation:

```
news = (dates.assign(Value=dates['Title'] + '\n' + dates['Description'])
             .groupby('Date')['Value'].agg('\n'.join).to_dict())
print(news)

# Output
{'2003-02-10': 'A\nage\nB\nnumber\nC\ntotal\nD\npercentage',
 '2003-02-11': 'E\ndivision',
 '2003-02-12': 'F\ncumulative',
 '2003-02-13': 'G\nampersand\nH\nvalue'}
```

A simpler way without `assign`:

```
news = (dates['Title'].add('\n').add(dates['Description'])
                      .groupby(dates['Date']).agg('\n'.join).to_dict()
```

**Performance**

For 400K records and 365 groups:

```
%timeit dates['Title'].add('\n').add(dates['Description']).groupby(dates['Date']).agg('\n'.join).to_dict()
121 ms ± 552 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Update**

> For learning's sake, I also want to know how to execute by applying a loop

```
from collections import defaultdict

news = defaultdict(str)
for date, df in dates.groupby('Date'):
    val = df['Title'] + '\n' + df['Description']
    news[date] += '\n'.join(val)
print(news)

# Output
defaultdict(str,
            {'2003-02-10': 'A\nage\nB\nnumber\nC\ntotal\nD\npercentage',
             '2003-02-11': 'E\ndivision',
             '2003-02-12': 'F\ncumulative',
             '2003-02-13': 'G\nampersand\nH\nvalue'})
```

Comment: For learning's sake, I also want to know how to execute by applying a loop.

Comment: Haven't you done it already? You can do a loop with `groupby`